# Removing a premake configuration when compatible toolset is not used

Tags: c++, premake

I'm using premake5 as project generator. I'm using it to generate makefile or Visual Studio where needed (Linux and Windows respectively).
I want to have a SAN (Adress/Undefined-Behavior SANitizer) configuration only when gcc or clang is used (other toolset doesn't support it) for my C++ project.
Sadly I did not successfully set it up.

I'm using premake5 Alpha13. I tried all sort of combinations of `not`, `or` and `and` inside the filter :

```lua
workspace "MyWorkspace"

configurations { "Debug", "DebugSAN", "Release" }

filter "toolset:not(gcc or clang)"
    removeconfigurations "*SAN"

filter { "configurations:*SAN", "toolset:gcc or clang" }
    buildoptions { "-fno-omit-frame-pointer" }
    buildoptions { "-fsanitize=undefined,address" }
    linkoptions { "-fsanitize=undefined,address" }
```

Tried `"toolset:not gcc and not clang"`, `{"toolset:not gcc", "toolset:not clang"}`...

I should end up with the 3 configurations when generating on Linux with GCC default, and only 2 when forcing `toolset "msc"` in premake5.lua. But I keep getting the same makefile in the 2 cases.

```
$ make help
Usage: make [config=name] [target]

CONFIGURATIONS:
  debug
  debugsan <- Showing-up when it wants
  release
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like remove command applies to "project configurations"

https://github.com/premake/premake-core/wiki/Removing-Values

so something like this seems to work

```
project "Test"
    kind "StaticLib"

filter {"toolset: not gcc or toolset: not clang"}
  removeconfigurations "*SAN"
```

You will not have the *san config in this project.
But i dont think there is a way to remove it from the "workspace" aka your make file.